# How to re-render this.state after the server goes offline

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm still new to React. I did some research about my question but haven't really found a good answer for my situation. So basically I have a server which has an array of student info in it. When the page is loaded and the server is online the list with students will be rendered on the page. My question now is: how can I rerender the page without having to refresh it when the server goes offline?

This is my code to put the details of the array in the this.state :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

        students: [],

        student: {

            name: '',

        }

    };

}

componentWillMount() {

    getServerData.getAll().then(response => {

        this.setState({students: response.message});


    });

}


placeStudents() {

    return this.state.students.map((student, i) => (

       <li key={i}> <Student name={student.name} id={student.id}/></li>

    ));

}
```

this is what I render :

```
 render() {

    return (

        <div>

            <ul>{this.state.students.length ? this.placeStudents() : <p>Server offline</p>}</ul>


        </div>

    );
}
```

So basically what I want to achieve is that the `<p> Server offline </p` will be displayed whenever the server goes offline , without having to refresh the whole page.

Here is how my Ajax call looks like:

```
export const getAll = () => {
return fetch('http://localhost:1337/students').then((response) => {
    if(response.statusText === 'OK') {
        return response.json();
    }
    throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
})
```

}

Any tips? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question, I think you're asking, "How can a website display: 'Server offline' whenever the server ceases to be available."

You have a couple of options:

1. Use a websocket and handle the connection dropped event
2. Use AJAX to poll the server (every 1 second, or something) and if the server fails to respond, display the unavailable message

If you choose option 2, I'd make a *really* simple endpoint on my server that does nothing other than respond with an HTTP 204 status code.

To be honest, I'd recommend against doing either of these. It's probably not worth the added complexity. I'd first question whether my app truly needs this functionality. Most likely, it doesn't.

[EDIT: As Nicholas pointed out, 204 is the correct status code for option 2... I was being lazy!]

Comment: Minor, but `HTTP 204` is a more appropriate status code  for option 2.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use something like [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to fetch students from the server on regular timebases. Below how your code may look like

```js
class Whatever extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        students: [],
        student: {
            name: '',
        }
    };
    // bind "this"
    this.getStudentsFromServer = this.getStudentsFromServer.bind(this);
    
    this.students = [{name: 'test1'},{name: 'test2'},{name: 'test3'}];
    }

  componentWillMount() {
    setInterval(this.getStudentsFromServer, 1000); // every 1 second.
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getStudentsFromServer();
  }
  // this simulates fetching data from server
  getStudentsFromServer() {
    let p = Promise.resolve({message: this.students});
     p.then(response => {
        this.setState({students: response.message});
        this.students.shift();
    });
  }
  
  placeStudents() {
    return this.state.students.map((student, i) => (<li key={i}>
         <p>name: {student.name}</p>
       </li>));
  }

 render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
            {this.state.students.length > 0 ? this.placeStudents(): 
           <p>Server offline</p>}
           </ul> 
        </div>);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Whatever />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```